# Ошибки при запуске JAR

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

Программа компилируется без ошибок. Но JAR, созданный в Idea, при запуске выдает ошибку(см. скриншот).
Пробовал менять на "getResource("../img/icon.jpg"))", указывать полный путь - не помогает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а чем собираете? идеей?

Comment: Картинки в архиве есть, проверил.  Путь "/img/icon.jpg" выдает ту же ошибку при запуске jar. Если менять путь на полный "C:/....", либо на "../img/icon.jpg", то перестает компилироваться сама программа с той же ошибкой. Совет про общий случай не понял..

Comment: @andrey-kalabin
1) Добавляйте текст ошибки не на скриншоте, а текстом, чтобы ваш вопрос индексировался в поиске
2) Какую строчку вам idea красным подчеркивает в классе `Field`?

Comment: 1. учту 2. строка 86 - frame.setIconImage((new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("img/icon.jpg")).getImage()));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наконец то разобрался. Проблема была в том, что файл назывался "icon.**JPG**" , а в коде "icon.**jpg**". Почему то это сработало при запуске в IDE, и не работало в JAR.